# Move document from one collection to another is overwriting the document

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

With the first operation by matching with id[1602271], its creating new collection and saving one doc(below-mentioned doc).

```
{
  "_id": "1602271",
  "date": "2019-02-11T06:25:13.425Z",
  "currentStatus": "scheduled",
  "statusHistory": [
    {
      "status": "onboarded",
      "date": "2018-11-02T10:07:11.167Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "preference_ready",
      "date": "2018-11-02T10:08:56.359Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "scheduled",
      "date": "2018-11-02T10:26:38.721Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

With the second operation id[1602131], it's not creating a new doc instead it's overwriting with the older one (above JSON).

```
{
  "_id": "1602131",
  "date": "2019-01-22T07:08:58.253Z",
  "currentStatus": "scheduled",
  "statusHistory": [
    {
      "status": "onboarded",
      "date": "2018-11-02T06:07:28.765Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "preference_ready",
      "date": "2018-11-02T06:11:30.777Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "scheduled",
      "date": "2018-11-29T05:48:57.871Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please refer below-mentioned code:

```
  public static final String STATUS_COLLECTION_NAME = "TeacherStatus";

  public static final String ARCHIVE_STATUS_COLLECTION_NAME = 
                "ArchiveTeacherStatus";

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match(where("_id").is(teacherId)),
                    out(ARCHIVE_STATUS_COLLECTION_NAME));
            mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, STATUS_COLLECTION_NAME, TeacherStatus.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as intended. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

> If the collection specified by the `$out` operation already exists, then upon completion of the aggregation, the `$out` stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection.

It will be possible in mongodb 4.2 where `$out` stage will accept an additional parameter `mode`, which can take values "replaceCollection" (what happens now), "replaceDocuments", "insertDocuments" (what you want).

---

Having re-read your code, why are you using **aggregation pipeline** with `$out` to copy **one** document? That's hunting sparrows with a cannon.

You can do it more reliably through the app. Read the document, then save it into the other collection.

Comment: Thanks, @Sergio. Is it possible to save in a new collection without creating a model/POJO and repository/DAO class/interface? If yes, how?

Comment: @BalaramaBadatya: I'm not familiar with java driver, but it's possible (and quite easy) in ruby driver.